# What do you call $ \frac{d^2 r}{dt^2}$ in polar coordinates?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, vectors, terminology, differentiation

In polar coordinates, one finds centripetal acceleration as:

$$ a_c = \frac{d^2 r}{dt^2}- \frac{v^2}{r}$$

Where $|r|$ is distance from center to particle, $v$ is tangential velocity.

My question is what does one call the $\frac{d^2 r}{dt^2}$ term..?

Comment: in polar coordinates $|r|$ doesn't really make sense, it's just $r$. Anyways $\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}$ gives the rate of change of the radial velocity of the particle so it can just be viewed as a radial acceleration.

Comment: Why do you think there is a special name for it? I haven't heard of one, but maybe there is one.

Comment: **Radial Acceleration**

Comment: See also [Difference between different radial and centripetal accelerations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/523639/difference-between-different-radial-and-centripetal-accelerationsdoubt), [Radial/centripetal vs. tangential/linear vs. angular acceleration](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/387870/radial-centripetal-vs-tangential-linear-vs-angular-acceleration) and [Types of circular acceleration?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108103/types-of-circular-acceleration).